# BOOST_PP_CAT: Outputting a comma `,`

Tags: c++, boost-preprocessor

How do I use the preprocessor (here I'm using Boost's `BOOST_PP_CAT`) to print output containing a comma `,`. For example,

```
#define PUBLICBD(base, derived) BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_CAT(base, BOOST_PP_CAT(<T , BOOST_PP_IF(1, BOOST_PP_COMMA, BOOST_PP_EMPTY)() )) , BOOST_PP_CAT( derived, <T>>))

PUBLICBD(B,D) // expect B<T , D<T>>
                            ^ missing
```

I've tried the approach outlined by the [boost docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/comma.html) but clearly it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think you need `CAT` in the first place? E.g. `derived < T >` are 4 separate tokens, they don't need concating.

Comment: Doh! Simply `#define PUBLICBD(base, derived) base <T ,  derived <T>>` works. Thanks for the tip @HolyBlackCat .